# How to resolve public class with internal constructor on AutoFac

Tags: autofac

I have this class to be instantiated in a unittest:

```
public class Customer
{
    internal Customer(Guid id) {
        // initialize property
    }
}
```

If I instantiate the test class from another (unittests) assembly with a `new Customer()` works because I added `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProject.Tests")]`

```
var sut = new Customer(Guid.NewGuid()); // works
```

But when i setup an autofac container in the other (unittest) assembly

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Customer>().AsSelf();
var container = builder.Build();
```

I can't resolve with autofac.

```
var theParam = new NamedParameter("id", Guid.NewGuid());
_sut = container.Resolve<Customer>(theParam); // throws exception
```

My best guess was that the internal constructor was not available. But adding `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Autofac")]` next to the other doesn't help.

The exception thown by Autofac is

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 
An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. 
Registration: Activator = Customer (ReflectionActivator), 
Services = [MyProject.Customer], 
Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, 
Sharing = None, 
Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope 
---> No accessible constructors were found for the type 'MyProject.Customer'.
```

Can Autofac not handle `internal` constructors?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Autofac can't locate non-public constructors because it uses the [DefaultConstructorFinder](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/develop/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/DefaultConstructorFinder.cs) class which searches only for public constructors by default.

You have to create your custom implementation of the IConstructorFinder interface like this:

```
public class AllConstructorFinder : IConstructorFinder 
{ 
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConstructorInfo[]> Cache =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConstructorInfo[]>();


    public ConstructorInfo[] FindConstructors(Type targetType)
    {
        var result = Cache.GetOrAdd(targetType,
            t => t.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors.Where(c => !c.IsStatic).ToArray());

        return result.Length > 0 ? result : throw new NoConstructorsFoundException(targetType);
    } 
}
```

Then you have to use the `FindConstructorsWith` extension method on type registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<Customer>()
   .FindConstructorsWith(new AllConstructorFinder())
   .AsSelf();
```

The `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` can't help in this case because it affects only the compile time.

Comment: That is a very clear answer in very decent English.  No need to apologize! :-)

Comment: I have to admit it sucks that Autofac needs something like this for handling internal classes. It shows that using `internal` keyword is not very popular approach.

Comment: @serafim-prozorov This is a good solution, I think, it is only necessary to add an additional condition for `AllConstructorFinder`: `...DeclaredConstructors.Where (c => !c.IsStatic)...` otherwise it is assumed that all static constructors can lead to exceptions like: “Cannot choose between multiple constructors with equal length 0 on type".

Answer (score -1):

if you want to register assembly types with at least only has one public constructor then you can use Autofac `Where` extension method like this.

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
        .Where(t => t.GetConstructors().Length > 0) //only public constructors
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Note: `PublicOnly` extension method registers only public types.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer, but the question is to resolve with an internal constructor. Which invalidates your answer completely, I think.