# How to handle internal constructors with Autofac

Tags: .net, autofac

I am working on a project to upgrade our app to .Net 4.8 (from 4.5.2). As you can imagine, this has been pretty fun.  Due to some dependency changes in other areas we also needed to update the version of Autofac that we are using - We were at 4.9.2, and I bumped it up to 6.1 cause, why not :)

I have been able to address changes to how pipeline events are handled (setting up middleware and all that), but now I am stuck with an issue with registrations. Basically, somewhere during the `.Build()` call a `NoConstructorsFoundException` is being thrown.

I understand, in general, why this is happening; the class in question is *public*, but the only constructor is *internal*.  This is in an assembly that is external to the project (though I do control it) - I have looked through the registration code within the "external" assembly to see if there was something there that could be changed, but not seeing anything obvious. I have tried using the `.PublicOnly()` extension, but I still end up with the same error.

```
builder
      .RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("MYASSEMBLY"))
      .PublicOnly()
      .AsImplementedInterfaces()
      .InstancePerDependency();
```

FYI - this is called from the main app as:

```
builder.RegisterModule<MYASSEMBLY.RegistrationModule>();
```

Ive also looked through the, literally, hundreds of registrations that are happening within the main app, and not seeing anything obvious.

Lastly, I did try changing the constructor to be public - which works. That class no longer causes this error - the next class that has only an internal constructor, though, does...

I saw this [issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/907), which is a few years old, which seems so similar, but not only does it not seem to apply here, it was fixed in a version earlier than what we had been using before when everything worked as expected.

Thoughts?
As a secondary - is there a way to easily see what has changed between 4.9.2 and 6.1 that might impact this?

Comment: Try adding an IConstructorFinder; check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52799160/114400

Comment: Oh, and the reason for the new behaviour is that constructor availability for registrations is now computed at build time rather than resolve time.

Comment: I had read that one, but didnt think it was what I was looking for at the time :)
Can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you want to add your own `IConstructorFinder` that includes 'internal' constructors in the list.

See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52799160/114400) for instructions on how to do it.

As for the change in behaviour, in v6 we changed it so constructors are located at container build time, rather than the first time the component was resolved.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  Thanks!